# App crashes on launch -android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML

Tags: android, crash

I'm new in android and I created a very simple app that goes through the build process without problems but when I try to launch (either on the emulator or in my android device) it crash (image bellow). I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this issue, I checked the logcat and I got some messages that I think might be pointing to the error origin but dont know what they mean.
The app crash on both emulator (PIXEL 2 XL API 27) as on my device One Plus 3T (android 8.0.0).

Bellow my xml, java code and log result

My xml layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="#de7905">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/texto_frase_dia"
    android:id="@+id/botaoNovaFraseId"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textoNovaFraseId"
    android:layout_below="@+id/botaoNovaFraseId"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/botaoNovaFraseId"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/botaoNovaFraseId"
    android:textSize="@dimen/texto_nova_frase"
    android:textColor="#fbfff7" />
```

My java code:

```
package ie.app.frasedodia;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textoNovaFrase;
    private Button botaoNovaFrase;

    private String[] frases = {
            "oi",
            "tudo bem?",
            "ddt?"
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textoNovaFrase = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textoNovaFraseId);
        botaoNovaFrase = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botaoNovaFraseId);

        botaoNovaFrase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Random randomico = new Random();
                int numeroAleatorio = randomico.nextInt( frases.length );

                textoNovaFrase.setText( frases[ numeroAleatorio ] );
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

My log output:

```
03-03 15:46:24.740 11858-11858/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: ie.app.frasedodia, PID: 11858
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ie.app.frasedodia/ie.app.frasedodia.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class TextView
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class TextView
                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class TextView
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert value at index 2 to dimension: type=0x4
                                                       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:730)
                                                       at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1226)
                                                       at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:820)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:75)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:71)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1024)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1081)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:772)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                       at ie.app.frasedodia.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6999)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6990)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

My gradle settings:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ie.app.frasedodia"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Add your XML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert value at index 2 to dimension: type=0x4
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:730)
```

leads me to think that you've got the wrong unit in `@dimen/texto_nova_frase`. The recommended unit is sp.

Comment: Jesus man thanks!! That's it. I miss the sp unit for that dim value. I add it and it worked! Thanks!